# How to DUMP object in freemarker ( .ftl )

Tags: freemarker

is there a way how to dump whole object and write it somewhere?

Like:
`var_dump()` in php
`console.log` in JS

I found something like `list`, so I try something like this below:

```
<#list calculation as c>
${c}
</#list>
```

But template fall with error. I appriciate any advise!

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the type of object you are iterating through. You can check the type of data your variable is and then output it appropriate (Reference: http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_isType)

Here are some examples:

```
<#if calculation?is_sequence>
  <#list calculation as c>
    ${c}
  </#list>
<#elseif calculation?is_hash_ex>
  <#list calculation?keys as key>
    ${key} - ${calculation[key]}
  </#list>
<#elseif calculation?is_string>
  ${calculation}
</#if>
```

Take a look at https://github.com/ratherblue/freemarker-debugger/blob/master/debugger.ftl for more examples on dumping data

Comment: Note that the line `${key} - ${calculation[key]}` can produce an error actually if calculation[key] is something complex 

I use to just write out the key and dump the value again with all these if checks